# existence of bounded open set $U\subset\Omega$ with $ F\subset U\subset\overline U\subset \Omega $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have seen again and again that the following statement is used in PDE.

> Let $\Omega$ be a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $F$ a compact subset of $\Omega$. Then there exists an open subset $U$ of $\Omega$ such that
>   $$
> F\subset U\subset\overline U\subset \Omega
> $$
>   *and* $U$ is bounded.

The first half of the statement can be done by the following more general proposition in topology:

A topological space $X$ is normal if and only if for each closed subset $E$ of $X$ and each open set $W$ containing $E$, there exists an open set $U$ containing $E$ such that $\overline U\subset W$.

Here is my **question**:

> How can I use the compactness of $F$ to show that $U$ could be bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ happens to be unbounded, just take $V = U \cap B$ where $B$ is any open $d$-dimensional disk (ball) containing  $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, we have the following statement.

> Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, $U$ an open subset of $X$, and $K\subset U$ a compact set. Then, there exists an open set $V$ with compact closure such that $K\subset V\subset\overline{V}\subset U$.

**Proof**:

Note that every point of $K$ has an open neighborhood with compact closure. By compactness, $K$ is contained in an open set $G$ with compact closure. If $U=X$, then set $V=G$. Otherwise, let $C=X\setminus U$. For each $p\in C$, choose an open set $W_p$ containing $K$ such that $p\notin \overline{W}_p$. Hence, $\{C\cap\overline{G}\cap\overline{W}_p\}_{p\in C}$ is a collection of compact sets with empty intersection. Therefore, by compactness, there exists points $p_1,\cdots,p_n\in C$ such that

$$C\cap\overline{G}\cap\overline{W}_{p_1}\cap\cdots\overline{W}_{p_n}=\emptyset$$

Now, set

$$V=G\cap W_{p_1}\cap\cdots\cap W_{p_n}$$

$\overline{V}$ is compact, since

$$\overline{V}\subset \overline{G}\cap \overline{W}_{p_1}\cap\cdots\cap \overline{W}_{p_n}$$

Comment: Ah, LCH. This appears in Folland's Real Analysis 4.5 Proposition 4.31. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jack Well, actually, I was reproducing a proof from Rudin's book in Chapter 2. ;-)

Comment: Which one of Rudin's books?

Comment: @Jack Real and Complex Analysis